# Python Scapy TCP SYN and TCP Port

Tags: python, scapy

Anyone have a solution when using scapy to grab the tcp syn flags and store the source ip, destination ip, port number in a dictionary?  I'm trying to build a tool that will take a pcap file and get that

This is what I've tired:

```
from scapy.all import PcapReader, TCP
from collections import Counter
count = Counter()
for pkt in PcapReader("testcapture.pcapng"):
    if TCP in pkt and pkt[TCP].flags & 2:  # TCP SYN packet
        src = pkt.sprintf('{IP:%IP.src%}')
        pkt.sprint
        count[src] += 1
        print(src)
```

This finds all the ips with syn flag, but i want to see port number

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Sorry I updated it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access the port values in `TCP` layer you can use `sport` and `dport`.
So you can adjust your code like this:

```
count = {}
for pkt in PcapReader("testcapture.pcapng"):
    if TCP in pkt and pkt[TCP].flags & 2:  # TCP SYN packet
        src = pkt.sprintf('{IP:%IP.src%}:{TCP:%TCP.sport%} -> {IP:%IP.dst%}:{TCP:%TCP.dport%}')
        pkt.sprint
        count[src] = count.get(src, 0) + 1
        print(src)
```